# Accidentally applied to my current company

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, job-change, ethics

### The Situation

I applied to a job posting of Company A in a country where my current company (Company B) does business. It turned out the job posting was of my current company (B), providing services for the company A. I was informed by the Company A contact about the situation and told me he would check the process for internal applicants.

I told her I was unaware of the implications of internal applications (like non-compete clauses between company branches or if it wasn't the proper channel), but that if everything was in order I would like to be taken into account for the process. Shortly afterwards, I was given the position contact in my own company (B) and after a brief contact I was told I would be contacted again. As is statistically the case, that never happened.

If it was any other company, I would not give it a second thought, but it is the one I'm working for right now, so a few questions arise.

### The questions

- Have I been blacklisted in any way by my current company?
- Did I hurt my standing or prospects within the organisation by
  revealing I was job hunting (actually testing the waters)?
- Which are the likely consequences of my actions and how should I
  navigate this situation?
- How should I act in the future? (Assume I'm a standard worker with
  standard motivations).

Comment: We can't know what exactly your current company thinks of the situation, nor whether or how they're likely to act, but them knowing you're job hunting is obviously not ideal.

Comment: what is the "standard" HR behavior in your company? In my case for an internal application it took them 6 months from when I applied to call me for the interview... it could be your application is still "work in progress"

Comment: Related: [Should I tell my boss I'm leaving before going job-hunting?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/46469) [How to respond if boss asks if I'm looking for a new job](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/55765)

Comment: Also, [Is it discrimination when my boss treats me differently after finding out that I'm looking for a new job?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11161)

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to be prepared to open up to your manager regarding your thoughts about moving on, or what it is about your current company that isn't meeting your needs.

There's a chance that your application hit the bottom of the bin and your manager/team won't know this has happened.  But you may as well assume that your manager will find out, so prepare yourself for that to happen.

In the meantime, stay quiet and do your job.

Comment: the only viable option